# Converting a regression problem into a classification problem

Tags: neural-network, regression, multiclass-classification

I have a regression problem where a neural network has to predict a value from $0$ to $19.999...$. I would like to convert this regression problem into a classification problem with the classes $0, 1, 2, ..., 18, 19$. Therefore I am using a $\mathrm{softmax}$-output layer.

Now, if I use a categorical crossentropy-loss, the loss is the same if the network classifies an input as $1$ instead of $14$ and if the input is classified as $13$ instead of $14$. I like to punish the loss more if the predicted value / class is farther away from the true value / class.

Is there a better loss function than categorical crossentropy for this use-case?

Comment: You could do a weighted categorical crossentropy, but why are you specifically turning it into a classification problem?

Answer (score 3):

I think what you should be looking for is [ordinal regression/classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_regression) in order to utilize the ordering of the classes.

Example [python](https://pythonhosted.org/mord/)/[matlab](https://github.com/ayrna/orca) implementations, with some extra resources.

For fast integration with your system, you could create a new ordinal regression model using the outputs of the already trained network as input to the new ordinal model and the true ordinal value as the output.

For another quick/dirty solution you could try simple Mean Absolute Error or Mean Squared Error, [according to this study](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-642-01818-3_25.pdf), between the predicted and target classes of your system, as it is right now, instead of the categorical cross-entropy error function.